# How can I create new records with has_many :through and honor :conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

Let's say I have a Course in which Students can enroll via a Membership (e.g. a has_and_belongs_to_many relationsip of Courses and Students).  Some memberships are for students who are just observing the class (not for credit, etc.), so:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships

  has_many :students,
           :through => :memberships

  has_many :observers,
           :through => :memberships,
           :source => :student,
           :conditions => { :memberships => { :observer => true }}
end
```

Here's what works great:

```
observers = Course.find(37).observers
```

Here's what doesn't work:

```
new_observer = Course.find(37).observers.build(:name => 'Joe Student')
```

I would have thought that one could build new records using the association and that would have generated:

1. A new Student record ('Joe Student')
2. A new Membership record (course_id = 37, student_id = (joe), observer = true)

But instead I get:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Membership expected, got Array
```

I'm sure I'm totally confused about how this and would appreciate any insights!  I've also tried to do this with named scopes on the Membership model, but I can't seem to get has_many to use a scope in the association.

Thanks so much for any help possible!

Answer (score 7):

I believe that you have encountered a Rails bug. I tried the same thing on my box (2.3.4) and it gives me the same error which doesn't seem right at all. Additionally I also tried the work around of:

```
course = Course.first
course.observers << Student.create(:name => "Joe Student")
course.save
```

But this creates a membership with the observer field set to **false**!

The final ugly workaround I came up with was creating the `Membership`record manually:

```
Membership.create!(:course => Course.first, :student => Student.first, :observer => true)
```

I've [created a ticket for this](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/3316-has_many-through-with-conditions-fails) and I'll be investigating further after breakfast.

**EDIT**: I have, as promised, investigated further and found if you change your `:conditions` Hash to an Array such as:

```
:conditions => ["memberships.observer = ?", true]
```

It works as intended. I also have a [github repository](http://github.com/radar/course-student-membership-bug) with example code and instructions to duplicate.

Comment: Thanks!! Very helpful!  Alas, still not quite 100%. The observer boolean is not set in sql:

c.observers.create!(:name => 'abby') =>

Student Create (2.0ms) INSERT INTO "students" ("name", "updated_at", "created_at") VALUES('abby', '2009-1
0-04 12:41:35', '2009-10-04 12:41:35')
Membership Create (0.0ms) INSERT INTO "memberships" ("observer", "updated_at", "student_id", "course_id", "
created_at") VALUES(NULL, '2009-10-04 12:41:35', 4, 2, '2009-10-04 12:41:35')

** Note the value (NULL) for observer.

Comment: Stupid question: is this issue still present or hash conditions work fine when building a record? (setting `observer: true`). Or maybe there is a better way (we are talking about rails4)