# Rails has_many :through with conditions and building associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many-through

I'm having problems building an association that is a `has_many :through` with conditions.  I have this model:

```
class Contact < AR
  has_many :group_contacts
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_contacts, :conditions => {:groups => {:published => true}}
end
```

problem happens when I try to instantiate a group from a contact.  With the above syntax, I get an error:

```
contact.groups.build
=> ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: groups
```

But when I use the following syntax it works:

```
has_many :groups, :through => :group_contacts, :conditions => ['groups.published = ?', true]

contact.groups.build
=> #<Group id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, published: true>
```

I see a reference to the exact problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514880/how-can-i-create-new-records-with-has-many-through-and-honor-conditions).  It is said a ticket would be filed for this bug (back in pre- rails 3 versions).  I can't find anything however on `rails 3.0.x`.

I'm using 3.0.8.  Has anyone else found this issue?

*Further Notes*:

I've also found that when I'm building groups, it actually ignores my conditions on the association when building.  The only reason my above build had `published => true` is because it's the default in the db.

This seems like a regression, can anyone else verify this?

Comment: Is it possible you meant: `has_many :groups, :through => :group_contacts, :conditions => {:groups => {:published => true}}` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
has_many :groups, :through => :group_contacts, :conditions => {:published => true}
```

or

```
has_many :groups, :through => :group_contacts, :conditions => {"groups.published" => true}
```

Comment: ah right...  i'm totally used to having conditions on other joined models ie `:conditions => {:some_model => {:attr => true}}`, but I guess when the conditions are on the actual `has_many` model, you don't need to specify it.   thx