# rails has_many :through with conditions on aliased association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

This kind of goes along with [my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067907/rails-has-many-through-with-conditions-and-building-associations) about `has_many :through` with conditions, but I've found another problem.

Given this class:

```
class Contact < AR
  has_many :group_contacts
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_contacts, :conditions => {:published => true}
  has_many :anonymous_groups, :through => :group_contacts, :source => :group, :conditions => {:anonymous => true}
end
```

My problem happens when I try to include the `anonymous_groups` with `contacts`:

```
Contact.includes(:anonymous_groups)
```

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "contacts"

The reason for this is the generated sql is incorrect.  It's something akin to:

```
SELECT "group_contacts"."id" AS t0_r0 ... "groups"."anonymous" AS t1_r5 ... LEFT OUTER JOIN "groups" ON "groups"."id" = "group_contacts"."group_id" WHERE ("group_contacts".contact_id IN (...) AND ("contacts"."anonymous" = 'true'))
```

Paraphrased of course, but look at the final condition.  It's put the anonymous condition on `contacts` rather than `groups`

Now, we can alleviate this query error (which i'm sure is a bug) but doing something like:

```
has_many :anonymous_groups, :through => :group_challenges, :source => :group, :conditions => { :groups => {:anonymous => :true} }
```

This puts the condition on the correct table in sql, but when I try to build an anonymous group, I get this:

```
contact.anonymous_groups.build
```

> ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: groups.anonymous

So it works for querying but not for building.  I'm quite certain this is a bug, but I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this or has a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like `:conditions => "groups.anonymous = true"` should work fine.

Comment: That's bizarre,  I tried doing: `:conditions => {'groups.anonymous' => true}` and that failed for the same reason.  But doing it in a straight up string works.  Bizarre.  Thanks a bunch